# Help needed if possible!

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I'm applying for visa (re-applying to the UK for EEA FM) tomorrow and I've attached this letter which I want to enhance. Can you please help me with that?

Here's my letter to the consulate:

> To whom it may concern,
>   I am writing to you to clarify my situation why I did not provide satisfactory evidence of my relationship with my wife what led to a refusal, and all respectfully demanding you to review the decision you took towards us.
>
> I am the EEA national family member, (my name), I am married to a Romanian, (my parter's name) who is settled in the UK, arriving there on the 9th February 2014. 
>   We've been together for 3 years and 8 months (44 months), and have been married a year ago, on the 11th Nov 2015. My wife has visited me twice in my country, Algeria.
>   I applied to the UK for an EEA Family Permit on 19th Oct 2016, and provided a file to show that we have a genuine marriage. I was aware that the supporting documents are crucial, and included photographs of my wife pictured with my parents, brothers and cousins.
>
> On the cover letter we’ve listed what documents we were providing, the communication evidence was included, I keep in touch with my wife daily, but we did not show the proof of  communication for the reason that how difficult it is to back to the year 2013, since our relationship began and go through such long period of 44 months to obtain the conversation history, we didn’t give it such significance that the Family Permit request would be refused due to it.
>   Another reason why I did not include our communication proof is that I didn't know how to attach that sort of evidence to the visa application (download and print or download FB and Skype conversations onto USB flash?). I went ahead and applied without any proof of our communication. 
>   I had the right to appeal against the refusal, but my wife and I have chosen to re-apply as you stated that you’re expecting to see our communication evidence covering up the period we’ve been together. This time we did include the evidence of our chat history.
>   We strongly believe that refusal was wrongly taken, thus we are re-applying again, including what you are expecting of evidence to prove our marriage is genuine, none of a sham marriage or relationship of convenience. We hope that you examine our application, and revise the decision you gave towards us.
>   We would appreciate your attention to this matter.
>   Faithfully yours, 
>   My name

Answer (score 1):

*I would suggest brevity, and not repeating what is already known; no 'hot' words like 'demand' etc.*

To whom it may concern:

I am writing to ask for clarification on what led to a refusal of my visa application, and requesting a review of the decision.

I am the family member of an EEA national family member, married to a Romanian, (my parter's name) who settled in the UK, arriving on the 9th February 2014. We have been together for 3 years and 8 months, and were married on the 11th November 2015. My wife has visited me twice in Algeria.

I applied to the UK for an EEA Family Permit on 19th Oct 2016, and provided a file to document our relationship and marriage, along with family photographs which include my wife.

Although my wife and I are in daily communication, we failed to include evidence of our conversation history, particularly since much of it has been via Facebook and Skype.

While I had the right to appeal the refusal decision, my wife and I have chosen to re-apply and have taken care to include our communication evidence throughout the time we’ve been together.

We do hope that your review of our application will result in a favorable decision.

Thank you for your consideration.

Respectfully, 
My name